What is the korean letter to represent the "oo" sound in the English word "moon"?
you can click on the following hyperlink to listen to how English Americans say the word "moon".
The same sound can be heard in the following English words:

tune
soon
noon
spoon
June
Room
Doom
boom
Whom
Prune
Dune
Strewn
Rune
Tomb
Croon
Suit
Zoom
Womb
Broom
Bloom
Gloom
Groom
Loom
Fume
Plume


The American English, the word moon is pronounced /mun/ in IPA.  The same /u/ sound is found in tune (/tun/) and soon (/sun/).
In Hangul, the vowel ㅜ is pronounced /u/. For example, the character 문 can be used to represent the sound of the word "moon" (notice the ㅜ between ㅁ and ㄴ).
Additionally, "tune" can also be pronounced as /tjun/. In this case, you could write it as 튠, using the vowel ㅠ, which represents the /ju/ sound.
